# Show the messagebox without interrupt the process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a python program to scrape a website every 10 seconds, to capture the new data updated. Each time the program find a new data, I use MessageBox to bump it in my screen, just for notification. However, the evaluation process will be interrupt, unless the user (namely, me) press the OK button. How to prevent such interruption?

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, 'something!', "title!", 0x00001000)
```